# Можно ли установить значения обычному массиву с помощью цикла for each в Java?

Tags: java, foreach

Доброго времени суток коллеги. Решал простую задачу.
Обычный `for` мне показался слишком ординарным. Я попытался решить задачу юзая `for each`, и ... у меня не получилось ๏̯͡๏.

```
double x [] = {255, 0 , 212};

for(double g : x) {
    g = g/255;
}
```

На выходе массив остался, прежний, а хотелось, чтобы стал `{1, 0, 0.82}`.

Я так понял, что в этом цикле можно прочитать значения - потому, что `g` - это всего лишь копия.

**Вопрос:** Можно ли циклом `for each` изменить значения в данном массиве, чтобы по выходу из цикла, в данном примере было `{1, 0, 0.82}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно если использовать переменную индекса:

```
double x [] = {255, 0 , 212};

int i = 0;
for(double g : x){
     g = g/255;
     x[i++] = g;
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо в моём примере работает. А ошибок не будет если, скажем 50 элементов? For each всегда ли с нулевого элемента обход начнёт?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, не кончится ли ситуация однажды тем что, что третий элемент станет на место первого?

Comment: Нет не будет, если в одном потоке. Он работает примерно так же как итератор.

Answer (score 5):

Вы меняете итерационную переменную `g`, а не контент массива. Дело в том, что итерационная переменная - это просто копия из массива.

Поэтому ответ - нет, внутри for each менять массив таким образом нельзя.

Изменить можно только так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
        g[i] = g[i]/255;
}
```

Comment: Где здесь используется цикл for each?

Comment: @RomanC Так я же писал, что данные в массиве через for each в том виде, как хочет автор - нельзя. Для этого надо писать обычный цикл. И привел пример как можно и как я считаю - будет лучше.

Comment: Нельзя использовать цикл for each?

Comment: @RomanC Учитывая пример в вопросе - нельзя, учитывая допольнительные переменные, обвязки и т.д. - Можно. Я отвечал на вопрос не формально, а с учетом семантики и желания человека понять - можно сделать как он хочет или нет.

Comment: Неинтересно. Мы все так тоже умеем.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать внутри лямбд внешние переменные типа не очень хорошая практика, но можно ещё с помощью Stream API:

```
double x [] = {255, 0 , 212};

IntStream.range(0, x.length).forEach(i -> x[i] /= 255);
```

Comment: Спасибо, откуда вы всё это знаете?

Comment: Ну, пишу код на Java, не?)